# Не работает медиa запрос в scss

Tags: scss, media

проблема в том что, не работает медиа запрос, при этом названия классов совпадает, например я хочу уменьшить шрифт, а он не уменьшаеться, но в инспекторе показывает этот код зачеркнутым (Снимок-экрана(29).png). А еще, до этого я делал адаптивное меню и все работало.[в инспекторе зачеркнуто](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AedBo.png)

[image: Адаптивное меню сверху работает, а дальше (класс а) вообще не реагирует не на цвет не на размер]

Comment: Зачеркнуто, потому-что приоритет отдан другому стилю, либо ставьте `!important`, либо добавьте точнее путь `header .a h1`, а не просто `.a h1`, если смотреть с точки зрения логики, то `header .a h1` более точнее, чем `.a h1`, соответственно и стили в случае перекрещивания будут отданы тому, кто точнее обозначил себя, если же оба точные, значит стиль будут определен последним изменением.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.